# Immediate/Force Azure File Sync

Tags: azure, azure-files

So I've been looking for a solution to Immediately syncing files uploaded to Azure in Azure File Sync and hadn't found any solutions.

I found this round-a-bout way of doing it, so I thought I would share it so other people who want to use this service have a word around while Microsoft implements it properly

**Method**

1. Create a duplicate of the item you want to pull from Azure (e.g. Foo.exe). Make sure its larger than 64KiB
2. Azure File Sync will upload it to the Cloud and also pull down the duplicate item (the one you wanted) but it will append a "- Cloud" to the duplicate file. (So now you have Foo.exe and Foo - Cloud.exe)
3. Delete the file you created (Foo.exe)
4. Remove "- Cloud" from the file that was pulled from the cloud (Foo - Cloud.exe -> Foo.exe)
5. Your done

I've also made the comment here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/33072151-enable-immediate-sync-after-changes-on-the-azure-f (but messed up the file size requirement)

Answer (score 0):

**Method**

1. Create a duplicate of the item you want to pull from Azure (e.g. Foo.exe). Make sure its larger than 64KiB
2. Azure File Sync will upload it to the Cloud and also pull down the duplicate item (the one you wanted) but it will append a "- Cloud" to the duplicate file. (So now you have Foo.exe and Foo - Cloud.exe)
3. Delete the file you created (Foo.exe)
4. Remove "- Cloud" from the file that was pulled from the cloud (Foo - Cloud.exe -> Foo.exe)
5. Your done